# Jquery find multiple selectors dont work

Tags: jquery, indexing, selector, contains

i am now making Searcher for table, and now i get prob.

This is code that not work:

```
var temporary = $(this).parent('tr');
temporary.find("td:nth-of-type("+indexColumn+"):contains(is)").css("background","yellow");
```

If i write it separatly like that, it works:

```
temporary.find("td:nth-of-type("+indexColumn+")").css("background","yellow");    
temporary.find("td:contains(is)").css("background","yellow");
```

I am getting this error if it is not written separatly:

```
"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: nth-of-type"
```

Where is my fault?

Thanks for any response.

**UPDATE:**

```
<table> 
   <tr> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> </tr>
   <tr> <td class="stat"></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> </tr> 
   <tr> <td class="stat"></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> </tr> 
</table>
```

It finds td with `class="stat"` and then i want get for example 4th column which contains any specified text

**ANSWER:**
Thanks for All responses.
I updated jQuery on 1.10.2 and it works.

Comment: What is your HTML structure?

Comment: <table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="stat"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="stat"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

It finds td with class="stat" and then i want get for example 4th column which contains any specified text

Comment: @user2899587 Edit your question to add the HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your structure, I have to assume that you don't have any `td` elements which match **both** `:nth-of-type("+indexColumn+")` and `:contains(is)`.

If you want to select `td` elements which match `:nth-of-type("+indexColumn+")` **or** `:contains(is)`, you could combine the two queries by separating them with a comma, like this:

```
.find("td:nth-of-type("+indexColumn+"), td:contains(is)")
```

Edit-

In response to your comment, the `:nth-of-type()` selector was added in 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector

Comment: I forgot to specify that  i am getting an error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: nth-of-type", but if i wrote it separate it is without error, but i need combine this two condition for td

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: This doesn't explain why they would work separately, but the `:nth-of-type()` selector was added in 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet is finding the nth column that contains is.

Your second snippet (where you "write it separately") is finding:

1) The nth column

2) Any column that contains is.

The first one doesn't work because your html must not have `is` contained in the nth column.

Comment: I now update post, can you look at it again? thx for response